# How to bound the integral mean value theorem number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1/60]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that

1. $\int_0^{1/60} f(u)\:\mathrm{d}u=8/5$
2. $0\leq f(u)\leq 144$ for all $u\in [0,1/60]$
3. $f(1/60)=f(0)=0$

I want to prove that there exists $c\in[0,1/60]$ such that $|f'(c)|=25920$.

For that I already made a little progress: using the mean value theorem for integrals we have that there exists $\alpha\in (0,1/60)$ such that
$$f(\alpha)=60\int_0^{1/60} f(u)\:\mathrm{d}u=96.$$
Then, if I could prove that $\alpha\leq 1/270$, the mean value theorem would imply the existence of $c\in(0,1/60)$ such that
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(\alpha)}{\alpha}\geq 270\times 96 = 25920.$$
By Darboux's theorem, knowing that $f'$ has to be $0$ somewhere, we know that $f'$ has to be $25920$ somewhere. However I don't know how to prove that $\alpha\leq 1/270$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this helps, but maximum derivative is minimized when the function is distributed as follows:

[image: Fig 1]

Then you can solve for x, knowing the area, and you get:

$$x=\frac{1}{180}$$

Then the max slope is:

$$\frac{144}{1/180}=25920$$

This means that whatever the shape ef your function is, there must be a point $c$ where $|f'(c)|=25920$. I don't know yet how to show it formally, but this may be a clue.

Comment: Nice intuition, +1.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the OP, $f'$ has a zero on $(0,1/60)$ and derivatives have the Darboux property, so it is enough to prove that $|f'(c)|\ge 25920$ for some $c \in (0,1/60)$.

Assume, on the contrary, that $|f'(c)| \lt 25920$ on $(0,1/60)$.

The line $y = 25920 x$ intersects the horizontal $y=144$ at $x = 144/25920=1/180$, and it follows by [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) that for all $x \in (0,1/180)$:

$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c) \lt 25920 \;\;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{for some}} \; c \in (0,x) \;\implies\; f(x) \lt 25920 x  \;\;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{for}} \; x \in (0,1/180)
$$

Then:

$$
\int_0^{1/180} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \;\;\lt\;\; 25920 \int_0^{1/180} u\,\mathrm{d}u = 25920 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{180}\right)^2 = \frac{2}{5} \tag{1}
$$

Repeating the same argument for $\,f(1/60-x)\,$, it follows by symmetry that:

$$
\int_{1/90}^{1/60} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \;\;\lt\;\; \frac{2}{5} \tag{2}
$$

Also, trivially:

$$
\int_{1/180}^{1/90} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \;\;\le\;\; \int_{1/180}^{1/90} 144\,\mathrm{d}u = 144 \cdot \frac{1}{180} = \frac{4}{5} \tag{3}
$$

In the end, $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ imply that:

$$
\int_{0}^{1/60} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u = \int_{0}^{1/180} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u + \int_{1/180}^{1/90} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u + \int_{1/90}^{1/60} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \;\;\color{red}{\lt}\;\; \frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{5} = \frac{8}{5}
$$

The latter contradicts the premise $\int_0^{1/60} f(u)\:\mathrm{d}u \color{red}{=}8/5$, so the starting assumption that $|f'(c)| \lt 25920$ cannot hold, which completes the proof.

As a final note, the above proves the stronger statement that $\max\{\,|f'(x)|\,\} \ge 25920$, and equality holds iff $f(x)$ is the trapezoidal function described in [Francisco Abusleme's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2904415/291201).